# How skype show my username (in log-form inside app) after i registered in... firefox?

Tags: skype

I never wrote my login before in Skype (it is impossible, I came up with it just now...) but when I run Skype after registering through website (using firefox) login field was already filled. How they do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd presume (just a wild guess) it read a cookie with the username, set by the registration process.